# How to use Oracle sql to put the first date on top and the rest of dates in reverse order?

Tags: oracle

When I use order by easily to get a query result like this,

name | date
Kev 2018/3/29
Lee 2018/3/28
Mel 2018/3/27
Fiona 2018/3/26
Jason 2018/3/25

but now how can I achieve the following sorting results?

name | date
Jason 2018/3/25
Kev 2018/3/29
Lee 2018/3/28
Mel 2018/3/27
Fiona 2018/3/26

Comment: Your example doesn't match the title. It doesn't put the last row on top, it puts the first one. And the other rows are not in order, they are in descending order. Please edit either the title or the example to make them consistent with each other.

Comment: OK, you edited the post; but the result you "want to achieve" still has the first date on top and the rest of the dates are in reverse order. So the title is wrong? Is it so hard to fix it?

Comment: I am very embarrassed. As a Chinese code farmer, English is really the biggest short board and I always mean nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min(dt)` is the earliest date. `min(dt) over ()` is an *analytic* function - it computes the min date and it adds it as a "made-up" column to every row in the query. Then, `decode` will produce `null` if the first two arguments are equal and `dt` otherwise. I order by this result, descending, with `nulls first` - so the earliest date will appear on top, and the other rows are ordered descending by `dt`.

```
create table t ( name varchar2(20), dt date );

insert into t
  select 'Jason', to_date('2018/3/25', 'yyyy/mm/dd') from dual union all
  select 'Kev'  , to_date('2018/3/29', 'yyyy/mm/dd') from dual union all
  select 'Lee'  , to_date('2018/3/28', 'yyyy/mm/dd') from dual union all
  select 'Mel'  , to_date('2018/3/27', 'yyyy/mm/dd') from dual union all
  select 'Fiona', to_date('2018/3/26', 'yyyy/mm/dd') from dual
;

commit;

alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy/mm/dd';

select   name, dt
from     t
order by decode(dt, min(dt) over (), null, dt) desc nulls first
;

NAME                 DT        
-------------------- ----------
Jason                2018/03/25
Kev                  2018/03/29
Lee                  2018/03/28
Mel                  2018/03/27
Fiona                2018/03/26
```